# My application works in Flash, but not when I publish it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an application that used to work when I publish it, but now it doesn't for some reason. It works when I have it open in flash, and I test run it, but when I publish it as a .swf, .exe, HTML it does not work correctly. Some buttons work, some don't, the dynamic text does not appear. Flash gives me no error message when I publish. All my text are either classic static, or dynamic. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does it load any external files ? You might want to test the .swf in a browser with a debug flash player and a debug build.

Comment: I have a preloader.exe that loads the .swf of the app. That's it.

Comment: if you publish without the preloader, does it work ? You make no mention of his preloader in your question.

Comment: It does not work, but I think I may have solved the issue. I made another copy of the game, and flash started giving me errors in my code. Which is weird, because the game was working fine in flash, but when I made another copy it started giving me errors

Comment: It worked! Turns out their were a few minor errors in the code and that's why things wouldn't show up!